# Remark or comment in a HTTP Query?

Tags: http, url

I searched around quite some time now (reading also the RFC1738) but have not found an answer yet:

I wonder if, in principle, it is (from the definition) possible, to add a "comment" or "remark" to an URL / http-query-string, so that this part is simply ignored (without error nor operation) by the receiving server?

Comment: Possibly - But why would you want to do this. It is up to the server to consider/ignore whatever it wants to.

Comment: Is this for debugging purposes? If so, there are [better ways of debugging](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) network requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relevant specs are RFC 3986 and RFC 7230. And no, there's nothing that *always* will be ignored.